# Force vs Stroke for Open-ended Solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

If I understand correctly, the force (F) versus stroke (x) curve for a solenoid which is open ended (there is no plunger stop in the middle) is something like the curve below:

[image: ideal solenoid]

The plunger is forced to the center of the solenoid where the forces balance and net 0, so there's presumably a point at the axis intersection. I'm interested in what happens at small displacements on either side of x=0.

From informal testing, I believe this is a function of the proportion of plunger length to solenoid length. From my tests done with a plunger which is ~double the length of the solenoid, the peak force occurs when an end of the plunger is aligned with the end of the solenoid as shown:

[image: ends-aligned]

When the plunger is further inserted there is still a net force acting to pull the plunger to be centered in the solenoid, but it is a smaller force.

[image: inserted further]

My theory is that the force profile in this case is actually something like:

[image]

Where the width of the transition region x= +/- ℓ is proportional to how much longer the plunger is than the solenoid. Are my observations above generally expected/sensical? Can I adjust the slope of the transition region by varying this dimension relationship?

I'm also interested in how linear the force curve region of x = +/- ℓ is. How can I predict this region?

Thanks!

Comment: Roundly, if you make the whole thing longer and thinner you'll lengthen the linear region, and if you make it shorter and fatter you'll shorten the linear region.  The details can all be calculated, by FEA if not by closed-form solutions.